# No response when running tflite image classification on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I made tflite a model using the google teachable machine image project and when I run the model using

```
python3 classify_picamera.py   --model /home/pi/tflite1/PP/model.tflite   -labels /home/pi/tflite1/PP/labels.txt
```

I get no response.

This is the image classification code I am using:
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/raspberry_pi/classify_picamera.py

Here is a video showing what happens https://youtu.be/Ya4B-EpqiII

Comment: print something as logs to see what is happening ( or show it here ), and another this is that you should have a space between `labels` and `/home`

Comment: Check `top -u $USER` command from another the terminal to see if the process is running. Check memory and CPU usage.

Comment: This is what happens when I run the code: https://youtu.be/Ya4B-EpqiII